# Will socket.recvfrom always return a valid address?

Tags: networking, sockets

I'm working on a communication protocol that should support self configuration by broadcasting / multicasting the peers' address over the local network. The intuitive way would be to broadcast the address, but as it turns out, it's pretty hard to reliably figure out the local IP address of the current machine (depending on the configuration, you might get "127.0.0.1" or another useless address).

The alternative is to not include the host address in the broadcast message, but to have the receivers call `recvfrom` on their socket which not only returns the received data, but also the sender's address. As I see it, that call is available on both Unix and Windows (one of my requirements) and probably some more platforms. My question now is, are there situations where this might fail and `recvfrom` returns an unreachable or otherwise useless address?

Comment: This question would be better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Blrfl: You're absolutely right, my fault. Would you care to vote for an off-topic close so we can move it over there?

Comment: I'm 70 points shy of being able to do that.  But I will write you an answer.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you limit this technique to only broadcast UDP, you should be fine. The only things that tend to mess with this are things like dual NAT or hairpin NAT. That's just not done with broadcasts that are local only anyway.

Comment: What about multicast (still UDP)? It wouldn't be necessary for the small number of peers I expect, but I'd like to support IPv6 networks that don't support broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

Any address is subject to becoming unreachable (and therefore useless by your definition) at any time.  Your software should be prepared to deal with that.

You can reliably determine the system's IP addresses (note the plural, more on that in a minute) by enumerating the interfaces.  How you do this will differ among platforms as there's nothing in a standard (e.g., POSIX) that specifies how it should be done.  Many Unixy systems have a `getifaddrs()` call; Windows does something else.  Either way, isolating that code should be easy.

Your software also shouldn't make the assumption that IP it comes across is "the" address.  On a system with more than multiple interfaces (which is most of them if you count the loopback), routings may change or someone may want to run your protocol on a segment that isn't on the same interface as the default route.

If you're going to broadcast a message, you need to do it once on every interface which is up, loopbacks included, unless you're configured to do otherwise.  The broadcast should also happen *from* each of those interfaces so it has the proper address.  You can't assume that other hosts on the same segment as any interface know about any other interface or have a way to route to their addresses.

If your protocol is intended for use only on connected segments, throwing away data from non-connected subnets would be a reasonable thing to do.